# How to add local users to wordpress without email password?

Tags: users, user-roles, profiles

I want to organize my posts with random names.Each post will have many authors (those are not actual/real authors).So i do not want to give them any email or password to log in.

Actually,i am trying to make project lists and each project has many contributers and each contributer can work on many project.i use Co-authors plus plugin to set authors to a post.
In the future, i'll show/list all projects which belongs to a specific author in author.php

- How can i add/upload profile picture to each user without gravatar?
- How can i create those users without email and password (this users
  are not real.so they won't log in site :p)

Can someone give me an advice to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue a month ago. As you I tried to use Co-Author Plus, but with the Plugin I haven't reached my goal. So , at the end, I thought that they are not real user and I make them like a custom taxonomy and I solved any problem

Comment: Thank you.I did not have much information on this taxanomies.It looks like exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I can't add the link cause I'm writing in mobile, but I Can Say you where ti look for: you Can consult the WordPress codex and look how ti create a new One or use a plugin as wp Types (Toolset Types) or Advanced Custom Fields.